# How to calculate a weekday averages for numeric values in r

Tags: r, date, time-series, mean

I have a `data.frame` that contains numeric values (`Rate`), Dates(`TrdDate`)- of a format of `1990-01-29`. I made a column that matches the weekday for each date and i want to calculate the average for each day.

```
      TrdDate Rate   weekday 
1. 1990-02-20  120    monday
2. 1990-03-20  100    monday
3. 1990-04-21  100   Tuesday
4. 1990-05-01  100  Thursday
5. 1991-01-01  150  Thursday
```

The desired output would be :

```
 weekday Rate
  Monday  110
 Tuesday  100
Thursday  125
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

```
DF <- read.table(text="TrdDate Rate   weekday 
 1990-02-20  120    monday
 1990-03-20  100    monday
 1990-04-21  100   Tuesday
 1990-05-01  100  Thursday
 1991-01-01  150  Thursday",strin=T,h=T)

aggregate(Rate ~ weekday ,DF,mean)
#    weekday Rate
# 1   monday  110
# 2 Thursday  125
# 3  Tuesday  100
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame is `df` you can do

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, weekday) %>%
  summarise(Rate = mean(Rate))
```